# Red Dead Redemption 2 and Grand Theft Auto V reporting griefing and hacking

Tags: red-dead-online

When I report players for griefing, nothing seems to come of it. Rockstar says that they are strict on griefing and hacking but they don't seem to do anything. Do they actually take action on reports for these issues?

Comment: It's not an answer but fact: Rockstar ***really*** doesn't give a fuck(sorry for the wording) about hackers and such. I've reported tremendous numbers of hackers and they really doesn't do anything. I mean, if they do care about them, why are we playing with hackers with that much of amount of time, when there is so-called cheater/hacker's lobby?

Comment: @Skye-AT Another issue I've read about is that hackers can actually detect and block the in-game reporting mechanism from working. I think the best way to actually report hackers is to contact https://support.rockstargames.com/ and include screenshots or video evidence.

Comment: @galacticninja Would it surprise you if I told you that I do exactly that every time?